# How to change position of the content in each element of tuple in this list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this tuple:

```
[("a", "b", 7), ("a", "c", 9),("b", "c", 10)]
```

I want to duplicate elements in above tuple by the mirror of each elements like this:

```
[("a", "b", 7),("b", "a", 7),("a", "c", 9),("c", "a", 9),("b", "c", 10), ("c", "b", 10)]
```

Please help me, I'm very appreciate with your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the tuples and make new tuples for your output list

```
def mirror(tuples):
    result = []
    for first, second, third in tuples:
        result.append((first, second, third))
        result.append((second, first, third))
    return result

print(mirror([("a", "b", 7), ("a", "c", 9),("b", "c", 10)]))
# [('a', 'b', 7), ('b', 'a', 7), ('a', 'c', 9), ('c', 'a', 9), ('b', 'c', 10), ('c', 'b', 10)]
```